# WIM file compression

Tags: compression, sysprep, wim

I build a custom windows 10 installer via sysprep (windows 10 pro Build 20H2). The windows created WIM-file is too large to my liking, over 9gb (want it to fit on a 8gb drive). Therefor I was trying to use [wimlib](https://wimlib.net/) to recompress the file and inject in into my windows installer.

I want to use secure-boot without creating a separate partition on my drive. So as the partition need to be fat32 therefor the intend is to compress and split the WIM-file.

Testing the original WIM-file, the installer completes without any issues.

Starting with the best compression I used LZMS solid (ESD-file). Compression worked like a charm, shronk to 5.6gb.
And installed using a NTFS drive (no secure boot)

```
winoptimize.cmd install.wim --solid
RENAME install.wim install.esd
```

Trying to split the file to make it fit on a fat32 drive, Windows fails to run the installer.

```
wimsplit.cmd install.esd install.swm 1000
```

Thinking that only a WIM-file could be split, my next attempt was to use the non-solid LZX. As expected the compression is a bit less (6.7gb), but should still fit a 8gb drive.
Installing with the compressed file fails with the same error "cannot open the required file install.wim"

```
winoptimize.cmd install.wim --compress=LZX:100 --chunk-size=2M
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to split a ESD-file? Or is this only possible with a WIM-file?

And what the maximum chunk-size is for LZX supported within the Windows installer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried splitting the image using Windows‘ own DISM?

Comment: Yes, splitting using DSIM is not possible on WIM-file with a chunk-size of 2M.
On a WIM created by wimlib with no chunk-size set, it works without issue. (meaning it defaults to 64kb)

De size difference is enorm
LZMS: 5.6GB
LZX2M: 6.7GB
LZX64kb: 7.5GB